# Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.04 on Acer E3-112 laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, acer

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on an Acer E11 laptop (model E3-112). The installation was successful. However I cannot boot Ubuntu. It directly boots to windows and does not even shows Grub. I checked F12 during boot and it only shows Windows boot manager. I tried every trick that I can find on the internet no luck.

Hope some of you can help me out. [Here is the boot-repair report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10477565)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Are you using a USB stick?  If yes, try upgrading your firmware or booting from CD/DVD as some UEFI firmwares have problems booting from USB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your bios is configured to search boots with UEFI firmware boot.
Windows8 is working because boots with it. 
It's possible that your Ubuntu doesn't install UEFI boot.

Search at bios configuration "SECURE BOOT" option and disable it. Try then.

Comment: I already disabled secure boot from uefi, before I installed ubuntu. Don't think this is the problem. It could somehow still be the case that secure boot is not actually disabled although it seems to be, but I don't know what else to do

Comment: Are you shure? With SECURE BOOT disabled, windows will not boot. Is it? Try to rescue you ubuntu with [Super Grub disk](http://wwwsupergrubdisk.org) and re-install grub2 with: `grub-install /dev/sdX`

Comment: well I am sure that in UEFI it says secure boot is disabled BUT windows still boots. Will try the rescue

Answer (score 0):

I got an equal problem on my Acer VN7-571G-56N0. It looks like Acer is modifing its BIOS quite hard so its optimised for Windows.

Did you install Ubuntu from an USB Stick? I can boot in my installed ubuntu by adding

```
menuentry "start OS on this computer" {
set gfxpayload=keep
    search --no-floppy --file --set=root /boot/grub/grubenv
configfile  /boot/grub/grub.cfg
}
```

to

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

on your USB Stick. You can start your Ubuntu over this entry when your USB Stick is plugged in during the boot.

For a permanent solution i just found 2 ways.

I didn't test this one yet, but you may try:

You can check your boot entries by

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

Now you deactivate the windows boot entries with

```
sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -A
```

Another way which worked for already is replacing the Windows Boot Manager with the grub. This is quite dirty, but i didn't find another way to deal with this.

You should first BACKUP your current settings by following the easy steps [here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-bcd-store-in-windows).

For replacing the Windows Boot Manager you boot into Windows and open the console as Administrator.

```
bcdedit /set {current} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

If you don't boot into the grub try this:

```
bcdedit /set {current} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```